# how put image view to right to row of listview

Tags: java, android, xml

how can i put `image view` to right of row of a `list view`?(square with image to right of row)

I hope that you can help me!

Thanks in advance everybody!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

this is my XML:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <CheckBox 
        android:id="@+id/chk_box"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/chk_box"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#000000" />
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/caratteristica"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/name"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/chk_box"
                android:textStyle="italic" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <!-- <TextView
             android:id="@+id/id"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
             android:textSize="12sp"
             android:textStyle="italic"/>-->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dist"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/caratteristica"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/chk_box"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textStyle="italic" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/valuta"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:textStyle="italic" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="196dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:hint="quantità"
        >
    </EditText>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

---

**AND THIS IS PIC:**

[image]

Comment: Image like Black border or simple..

Comment: a square to right of row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update Your Row to add image in right in center in**

I used the image of launcher you use what u take...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/chk_box"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/chk_box"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="#000000" />
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/caratteristica"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/name"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/chk_box"
                android:textStyle="italic" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <!-- <TextView
             android:id="@+id/id"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
             android:textSize="12sp"
             android:textStyle="italic"/>-->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/dist"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/caratteristica"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/chk_box"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:textStyle="italic" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/valuta"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:textStyle="italic" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="196dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/editText"
            android:hint="quantità"
            >
        </EditText>
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivImage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"

      android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
     />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: in class Holder i write this:        public ImageView image;
and now?

Comment: in class "pizza" what kind of variable is an Image View?

Answer (score 1):

try this may be it helps you

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:background="@drawable/iconsmile"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/checkBox" />
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
        android:text="I am here for you"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView1" />
    <TextView
        android:text="I am here for you"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView2" />
    <TextView
        android:text="I am here for you"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView3" />
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```